# Meaning of moving round

Tags: meaning, phrases

> If I lived in a hot climate I would try to avoid ***moving round*** much in siesta time.

I didn't catch the meaning of ***moving round***. I looked for the phrasal verb, but didn't get any useful results. I first thought that moving round = repeatedly moving on around something.

Comment: Round seems to be a typo of "around".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In American English the expression is usually stated as *move around*, which in this context  means to do any kind of physical  activity like walking.  It is the opposite of *stay in one place* or *stay put*.

It is possible to shorten *around* to *'round*, with the apostrophe included in the spelling. I'm not familiar with *move round*.

Oxford Dictionary has a [usage note](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/round#round__103) about  *around* and *round*. It is interesting reading, especially since there is different usage  in UK English and US English.

Comment: In speaking it sounds like moving round though...